# Why does PowerShell output change after loading assembly?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am getting some unusual output from `New-Item` **in a script** if I've first loaded an assembly with reflection. Why?

If I run

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
New-Item -Path "temp" -ItemType directory
```

I get the following odd output from New-Item:

```
PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\swoogan\Desktop\temp
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\swoogan\Desktop
PSChildName       : temp
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Name              : temp
Parent            : Desktop
Exists            : True
Root              : C:\
FullName          : C:\Users\swoogan\Desktop\temp
Extension         :
CreationTime      : 7/28/2014 11:03:10 AM
CreationTimeUtc   : 7/28/2014 3:03:10 PM
LastAccessTime    : 7/28/2014 11:03:10 AM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 7/28/2014 3:03:10 PM
LastWriteTime     : 7/28/2014 11:03:10 AM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 7/28/2014 3:03:10 PM
Attributes        : Directory
BaseName          : temp
Mode              : d----
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         7/28/2014  11:03 AM            temp
```

If I pipe the output of `LoadWithPartialName` to `Out-Null`, then I do get the expected output. I would like to understand what is happening here so I can anticipate these discrepancies in the future.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `LoadWithPartialName` instead of `Import-Module WebAdministration` ?

Comment: Why does it matter how the default formatter outputs the object to the screen (assuming it's a `DirectoryInfo` object in both cases)?

Comment: I get the second output in both Powershell 2 and 4, both before and after loading the assembly.

Comment: @Eris: 1) Yes, there is a specific reason. 2) Put it in a script, then try again.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The output of the script is changing based on unrelated code that is run earlier. It is both unexpected and undesired to have the results of a command change at (seemingly) random.

Comment: But if the output is a `DirectoryInfo` object, then the result is the same, regardless of how the formatter outputs it.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The text output (result) of the script execution is clearly different. Please see the question.

Comment: Get the output object both ways and inspect the type using `GetType()`. If the output object is a `DirectoryInfo` object, then both outputs are the same kind of object, even if the formatter displays it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out.

In the original case with the `LoadWithPartialName`, the output of the script is an array of `PSObject` since Powershell sends any unhandled object to the pipeline, and the items are of mixed types (0 = AssemblyInfo from Load; 1 = DirectoryInfo from new-item).

If you redirect the `LoadWithPartialName` to `[void]` or even save the output in a variable, the output of the script is a single `DirectoryInfo` object.

`PSObject` gets formatted differently than `DirectoryInfo`

Comment: This is probably correct, which is why I was asking the OP what the object types were. The output of the formatter is more or less irrelevant as long as the object types are the same.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out around the same time. Simply using $test = ""; $test2 = mkdir "temp"; $out = test.GetType(), $test2; $out; illustrates the change of the default formatter when a System.Object is in the pipeline.